# Cannot ping machine on ethernet while having two interfaces active (Ethernet and Wifi)

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet, ethernet

As the title says I cannot do it.

My computer is connected to the WiFi for internet, and to the Ethernet to LAN communication with the other computer. I have setup the Ethernet connection ipv4 routes to use this connection only for resources on its network , and also the IPv4 forward = 1.

The default connection is on WiFi, both connections are active. Default connection is WiFi.

When I disconnect from WiFi I can ping on the other machine over ethernet.
When I am connected to both I cannot ping on the machine over the ethernet.

I don't know how to solve this, can someone help me?

my route -n output is  (eno1 ethernet, slp58s0 WiFi)

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.43.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp58s0
10.68.0.0       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno1
192.168.43.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp58s0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you `ping`-ing using hostname or IP? Could be your hostname is not resolved when WiFi is enabled.

Comment: thank you, the hostname was actually not resolved. I added it manually to /etc/hosts

Comment: Awesome. Happy that it worked for you :-)